# How do I print out the dictionaries within a list that has a boolean value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a series of dictionaries within a list and they all contain the same key but different values. Basically, it consist of 4 key values.

Essentially, I wanted to filter out the rides that are close based on the `isOpen` value. As can be seen, they are in boolean format (True/False) so I used 1/0 but it kept returning:

> ```
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
> ```

This is the code I have so far:

```py
status = [
    {'name': 'Carrousel', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
    {'name': 'Balloon Flite', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
    {'name': 'Skyrush', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': False, 'single_rider': None}, 
    {'name': 'sooperdooperLooper','wait': 5,'isOpen': True,'single_rider': None},
    {'name': 'Fahrenheit', 'wait': 20, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None}
]

for i in status:
    if (status[i]['isOpen' == 1]):
        print (i)
```

Based on the values within the list, I want to print the rides that has a `isOpen` value of True.

Something like this:

```py
[
    {'name': 'Carrousel', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
    {'name': 'Balloon Flite', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
    {'name': 'sooperdooperLooper','wait': 5,'isOpen': True,'single_rider': None},
    {'name': 'Fahrenheit', 'wait': 20, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None}
]
```

If you look at the result, `Skyrush` is omitted because it is not open.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in how you're defining the `for` loop. Your code should look like this if you want a for loop that access by list element:

```py
for i in status:
    if i['isOpen']:
          print(i)
```

If you want to access elements in the list by index you should use this:

```py
for i in range(len(status)):
    if status[i]['isOpen']:
        print(status[i])
```

You managed to combine the techniques which has caused your issues. As others have said, to check if its a Boolean you only need to access the Boolean value by key, not evaluate to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list comprehension.

```
[el for el in status if el["isOpen"]]
```

This iterates over every dict in `status` and filters out the ones where "isOpen" is true.

If you want to modify your current technique to work, you should do:

```
for i in status:
    if i['isOpen']:
        print(i)
```

Here, `i` refers to an individual dict inside the list. You then check if its isOpen is true, and if it is, you print it.

Comment: I would use `d` just to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you're referring to the second technique, then yes, using `I` to refer to anything but an index is poor practice.

Comment: it works! thank you so much for the help! I was having trouble accessing the individual dict inside and no wonder it didn't work. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Two things to fix here:

```
for i in status:
```

`i` is an element from the list. So let's give it a better name:

```
for item in status:
```

Also, this means you can't do `status[i]` (or `status[item]`). Istead, use `item` directly. Finally, you want the value with the key `'isOpen'`:

```
    if item['isOpen']:
```

Note that you should not put the comparison `==` inside the brackets here. In fact, since this value is a boolean (`True` or `False`), you don't need a comparison at all.

Finally, you can print `item`:

```
        print(item)
```

Putting this all together:

```
for item in status:
    if item['isOpen']:
        print(item)
```

Answer (score 1):

Naming variables can help a lot.  Variable status is a list of dictionaries.  "i" is usually used as an index. Here is your code:

```
for i in status:
    if (status[i]['isOpen' == 1]):
        print (i)
```

Variable i is a dictionary, not an index in the list.  If you want the index, you should do

```
for i in range(len(status)):
```

But you really do not need the index into the list.  Do instead:

```
for rideDict in status:
     if rideDict['isOpen']: 
          print rideDict
```

For boolean values, you can just test the value "if rideDict['isOpen']".  You could do "if rideDict['isOpen'] == True" but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples using Python `lambda`,

```
list(filter(lambda x: x['isOpen'], status))
```

Using `itertools`,

```
from itertools import filterfalse

list(filterfalse(lambda x: not x['isOpen'], status))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for item in status:
  if item['isOpen']:
      print (item)
```